# How do I use compound boolean expressions in the version-selecting syntax on Documentation?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation, markdown, language-versions

How do I flag sections as being valid for different ranges of versions?

I can only see how to say something like "greater than 3.4". I need to be able to declare that something is valid in both python2 and python3, and some members of the community are claiming it isn't valid to just say "greater than 2.5" to imply that python3 is also covered. this is how you start version blocks for both flavors of python:

```
<!-- if version <Python 2.x> [gte 2.3] --> 
<!-- if version <Python 3.x> [gte 3.0] -->
```

But how would I specify that something is valid after both python 2.5 and python 3.0?

Is this a feature that can be added?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, at least from what I've tried. Should you find a way, please add it to the documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/documentation/4541/versions#t=201607311257015852603 , you know, because the makers of documentation could not be bothered to write a documentation themselves.

Comment: there's docs on Docs, but the docs on Docs are not officially presented in Docs :( http://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-versions

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you can nest multiple version blocks:

```
<!-- if version <Python 2.x> [gte 2.3] --> 
<!-- if version <Python 3.x> [gte 3.0] -->
content
<!-- end version if -->
<!-- end version if -->
```

Comment: yeah, that's better than nothing.  how do we propose a feature request?

Comment: @Conrad.Dean I guess with a question tagged [meta-tag:feature-request] and [meta-tag:documentation-proposals]